# when does the garbage collector of v8 engine of chrome is activated by default in nodejs

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection, v8

If my nodejs memory is reached upto 1.5GB and then i am not applying any load on it and the system is idle for 30 minutes then also garbage collector is not freeing the memory

Comment: you're assuming that GCs are time-triggered, which is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to say anything specific, like "why gc is not collecting the garbage" as you ask in the comments, when you say nothing about what your program is doing or how the code looks like.

I can only point you to good explanation of how GC works in Node and explain how to run GC manually to see if that helps. When you run node with the `--expose-gc` flag, then you can use:

```
global.gc();
```

in your code. You can try to run that code in a timeout, on a regular interval or at any other specific moment and see if that frees your memory. If it does, that would mean that the GC was indeed not running and that was the problem. If that doesn't free your memory that could mean that the problems is not with the GC not running, but rather not being able to free anything.

Memory not being freed after manual GC invocation would mean that you have some memory leak or that you use so much memory that cannot be freed by the GC.

If the memory is freed after running GC manually it could mean that it is not running by itself, maybe because you are doing a very long, blocking operation that doesn't give the event loop any chance to run. For example having a long running `for` or `while` loop could give such an effect.

Not knowing anything about your code or what it does, it's not possible to give you any more specific solution to your problem.

If you want to know how and when the GC in Node works, then there is some good documentation online.

There is a nice article by StrongLoop about how the GC works:

- [Node.js Performance Tip of the Week: Managing Garbage Collection](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-performance-garbage-collection/)

Also this article by Daniel Khan is worth reading:

- [Understanding Garbage Collection and hunting Memory Leaks in Node.js](http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2015/11/04/understanding-garbage-collection-and-hunting-memory-leaks-in-node-js/)

It's possible that the GC is running but it can't free any memory because you have some memory leak. Without seeing an actual code or even an explanation of what it does it's realy impossible to say more.

Comment: I already know about the concept that you are trying to make me understand. please go through my question that why gc is not collecting the garbage even though my system is idle for 30 minutes

Comment: @selftaught91 It's impossible to say anything more when you say nothing about what your program is doing or how the code looks like. I can only point you to good explanation of how GC works in Node and explain how to run GC manually to see if that helps. It's possible that the GC is running but it can't free any memory because you have some memory leak. Without seeing an actual code or even an explanation of what it does it's realy impossible to say more.